# DateFormat.parse fails to parse dates/times that look fine

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, timeofday

I'm getting the issue when converting string to `TimeOfDay`. It was working before but now I am getting the issue.

```
try {
    final format = DateFormat.jm(); //"6:00 AM"
    TimeOfDay day = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(format.parse("6:00"));
} catch(ex) {
    PLPrint(name: "CheckTest",value: "${ex.toString()}");
}
```

I have tried the format for parsing string:

1: 6:00 - FormatException: Trying to read   from 6:00 at 5

2: 6:00 AM - FormatException: Trying to read   from 6:00 AM at 5

3: 6:00:00 - FormatException: Trying to read   from 6:00:00 at 5

4: 6:00:00 AM - FormatException: Trying to read   from 6:00:00 AM at 5

5: 16:00 - FormatException: Trying to read   from 16:00 at 6

6: 16:00:00 - FormatException: Trying to read   from 16:00:00 at 6

I have tried almost all the formats but still getting the Format issue.

Comment: I tried to run your code with format('6:00 AM') -> TimeOfDay day = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(format.parse('6:00 AM'));
--> it's working and the result is: "TimeOfDay(06:00)"

Comment: @Aks You're probably using intl 0.18.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateFormat` `jm` skeleton uses a locale-dependent format and therefore can vary.  In the default locale (which I think is default to U.S. English locale), that format includes an AM/PM marker, and as of 2023 that marker is now separated with a Unicode non-breaking space (specifically U+202F):

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var format = DateFormat.jm();
  var s1 = format.format(DateTime(2023, 1, 1, 6));
  var s2 = "6:00 AM";

  print(s1);       // Prints: 6:00 AM
  print(s1 == s2); // Prints: false

  print(s1.runes); // Prints: (54, 58, 48, 48, 8239, 65, 77)
  print(s2.runes); // Prints: (54, 58, 48, 48, 32, 65, 77)
}
```

If you want `jm` to accept other types of whitespace, use [`DateFormat.parseLoose`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat/parseLoose.html) instead of `DateFormat.parse`:

> If `inputString` is accepted by `parseStrict`, just return the result. If not, attempt to parse it, but accepting either upper or lower case, allowing delimiters to be missing and replaced or supplemented with whitespace, and allowing arbitrary amounts of whitespace wherever whitespace is permitted. Note that this does not allow trailing characters, the way `parse` does.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var format = DateFormat.jm();
  print(format.parseLoose("6:00 AM")); // Prints: 1970-01-01 06:00:00.000
}
```

From empirical testing, the change to use a non-breaking space seems to have been picked up by `package:intl` in 0.18.1, so you also could consider rolling back to 0.18.0 as another workaround.

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/i18n/issues/743.